# Azure App Service Plan Scale Out Settings Won't Save

Tags: azure, azureportal

I am having an issue getting my Azure App Service Plan Scale Out Settings to save. The only thing in the plan is one web app. I am using Scale by schedule and performance rules. If I try to change anything such as the increase count by number, click Ok, then click Save, I get the Saving scale setting indicator and it never goes away or gives a success notification. I tried different browsers on different machines - same result. I went to the old portal and was able to reset the scale settings there - when I go back to the new portal, the changed old portal settings are reflected there but I still cannot save any changes in the new portal. The Activity log shows Update autoscale setting failed with Error code UnsupportedRequestContent, Message Request content is not well formed or supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must have been some unexpected data in the old profiles their web app couldn't deal with.  I deleted all the scale profiles and started with new ones.  That worked.  Issue resolved.  Since the issues always occurred with profiles that had originated in the old portal, it seems there may be some incompatibility between old portal profiles and new portal profiles.

Comment: And that is an example of how, when the portal doesn't work, the portal can be used to fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, how did you do this? I'm having a similar problem, but on the scale up settings page. My basic app won't downgrade to free or shared, even though it says it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835941/azure-web-app-wont-change-from-basic-1-small-to-free-or-shared-pricing-tier. Do you have any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: nmit026 I don't believe what I accomplished by deleting scale out profiles will help any with changing scale up settings.