# Azure web app won't change from Basic: 1 Small to Free or Shared pricing tier

Tags: azure

I'm testing different Azure web app pricing tiers. In the portal I clicked "Scale up (App Service plan)" and chose the B1 Basic pricing tier to test how the performance compared with F1 Free and D1 Shared. When I try to scale down from Basic to Free or Shared, it says "Successfully updated App Service plan", but it doesn't work. I've tried this over a week or so and it just doesn't work. I was able to switch between Free and Shared with no problems before this. Surely this is some sort of error? We must be able to downgrade?

Comment: Maybe there are other details you could share? As written, there's really nothing to go on. Also - have you tried simply creating a new app service plan with the different tier, for perf comparison purposes? Have you tried contacting support?

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks, there's actually a bug in the new portal. The old portal gives you a helpful error message. Would be good to get this fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the new portal has a few bugs. I tried to do this operation with the old portal and got a helpful error message:

`Cannot update the site 'test' because it uses x64 worker process which is not allowed in the target compute mode.`

If you choose a setting not available in a downgrade, for example 64-bit or "Always On" (confirmed), and then try to downgrade, it will say it succeeded when actually it failed.

And they won't let us use the old portal soon. Great.

Comment: Remember to send a support ticket to them about this. Only way it's gonna get fixed is if you report it.

Comment: @juunas you can vote for a fix here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/17266997-erroneous-success-message-when-downgrading-in-new. You can also use the smiley face feedback button in the portal.

Answer (score 23):

You must turn off the "Always On" feature of the Web App from the Azure portal "Application Settings" before changing (downgrading) the App Service Plan.

[image]

Comment: The portal has apparently been subsequently tweaked. `Always on` is now on the Settings | Configuration | General Settings tab.

Comment: You also have to switch the Platform setting to 32 bit

Answer (score 3):

"Always On" can be found here now:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; it was not possible to change the tier even after I changed the app service configuration to 32-bit. The problem was the other app services in the app service plan. After changing all the app services of the service plan into 32-bit, it was possible to change it to Free tier.